# Angular Getting access to variable via this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have my state example with the js:

```
 app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('example', {
            url: '/example',
            templateUrl: example.index,
            controller: function($scope) {
                console.log('selected', $scope.selected);
                console.log('selected', this.selected);
                     }
          });
});
```

I want to find out, why $scope.selected is undefined, but this.selected is defined (the array).

In the view I have  my directive:

```
<my-directive selected="selected"></my-directive>
```

with its controller:

```
 app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    scope: {
       selected: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $filter){
     $scope.selected= [{'name': 'otto'}];
    }
}
```

I need access to the $scope.selected to work with the array, that is created in the my-directive - Direktive !
I think this understanding is very important, so thanks for any help and advices

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide us a working example? For example using the internal code snippet tool  or Plunker or other services like that? Thanks

Comment: Hi, is the "<my-directive selected="selected"></my-directive>" is in example.index?? Please share the complete code either via plunker of internal code tool.